# Cancel event when delay was not met?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be able to cancel an event based on the amount of time an element is hovered on. Say when I set the delay to 500ms, when the element is being hovered on for less than that, an event should be cancelled, otherwise it is fired. The `delay()` and `setTimeout()` function seem incapable of doing that.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Sorry,submitted the post accidentally. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this instead of using jQuery `delay` method.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cvmgp/)**

```
var timeoutId = null;
$("selector").hover(function(){
   if(timeoutId)
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);

    timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        alert("do your stuff here");
    }, 5000); 
}, function(){
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone might come up with something cleaner but the code below will be able to handle what you are asking.  It requires 500 milliseconds to pass before the code inside the event can be triggered again.  Could probably clean it up so that timer/delayMet aren't ***potentially*** global variables.

I'm using `$('a').click` as an example selector and event.

```
var timer, 
    delayMet = true;

$('a').click(function () {

  if(delayMet === true) {
    // your code here
  }
  else {
    delayMet = false;
    setTimeout(function () {
      delayMet = true;
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel `setTimeout()` by doing the following.

```
var timer = setTimeout(function(){...},5000);
...
clearTimeout(timer);
```

From jQuery [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) docs:

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

Not sure if that is what you mean though.